# How can I set a css class to all child elements? (Angular 6, Ngx Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, angular, angular6, ngx-bootstrap

I have a CSS class like this:

```
.panel-mobile-navs > ul > li {
 width:100%
}
```

And on the HTML I'm using Ngx-bootstrap for a set of tabs:

```
<tabset class="panel-mobile-navs" > ... </tabset>
```

So I'm trying to change the css of the elements inside of it, when the page loads, the following HTML is generated inside the "tabset" element:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-reflect-klass="nav" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object 
Object]">
...
<li class="nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="nav-item,"> ... </li>

</ul>
```

But the class I made, does not apply to the ul and the li elements, am I doing CSS wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the css for the list elements is not overridden by some other css elsewhere?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? I ask because you have these classes: "class="nav nav-tabs". If you are, then the Bootstrap framework styles will be applied, and you would need to override them accordingly/properly

Answer (score 0):

this rule relies on the DOM structure to be exactly `TABSET.panel-mobile-navs > UL > LI`:

```
.panel-mobile-navs > ul > li { ... }
```

The framework you are using may be injecting DOM nodes that prevent the rule from working.  Try targeting the `.nav-item` class directly.

Answer (score 0):

What about to use descendant combinator(`.panel-mobile-navs ul li`) instead of child combinator(`.panel-mobile-navs > ul > li`)?

There are documents:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using descendant selector, use `class name` instead, it is considered more performant. Based on your markup, something like this would probably works:

```
// SCSS
.panel-mobile-navs {
    .nav-tabs {
        // styling for ul here
        .nav-item {
            // styling for li here
        }
    }
}

// CSS
.panel-mobile-navs .nav-tabs {
    // styling for ul here
}
.panel-mobile-navs .nav-item {
    // styling for li here
}
```

Make sure to inspect the rendered elements to see if css rules was loaded:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d8Kc.png)